# Resizing animated GIF in image creates artifacts

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to add a blank area around some animated GIFs using imagemagick, but in many cases the resulting larger animations have artifacts. For example, if I start with [this image](https://i.giphy.com/media/ziGG6gqt8OAIKpy25r/200w.gif)

[image: original image]

And run the following command (which has the `dispose` and `coalesce` flags which I've thrown in after seeing them online in the hopes they'll help)

```
convert input.gif -gravity center -dispose previous -extent 500x500 -coalesce output.gif
```

The result is the following

[image: output image with artifacts]

Is there a different command I can run that wouldn't gave the green splotches invade the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your syntax wrong for ImageMagick and also need to use -dispose none. You are adding a new color to your animation which likely already used 256 colors.

Input:

[image]

```
convert -dispose none input.gif -coalesce -gravity center -background green -extent 500x500 -layers optimize output.gif
```

[image]

Change the background color as desired, which you left out of your command.

Comment: Thank you. As an added note I can get this to work with `convert` but `mogrify` still has issues.

Comment: Mogrify is less flexible than convert. If you have more than one gif to convert, then write a script loop over convert.