# ImageMagick: Combine animated GIF with PNG frame

Tags: imagemagick, animated-gif

I have an animated GIF of a fixed size (600x200):
[image: Animated GIF]

I am trying to combine this GIF with a PNG frame:
[image: Frame]

The frame is larger than the GIF (640x260) but has a designated 600x200 space - the GIF just needs to be placed *behind* the PNG at a position of 20/20 pixels from the top left. The result should look like this, but preserve the GIF animation:

[image: Non-animated result]

How can I achieve this using ImageMagick?

EDIT: The closest I got was using this command (ImageMagick 7 on Windows):

```
magick testgif.gif -repage 610x232+5+5 -transparent white -coalesce -draw "image over 0,0 0,0 frame3.png" -transparent white out.gif
```

The result (which is also 2.79 mb large, too large to upload here, while the original GIF is 213 kb) shows some artefacts. I added `-dispose none` following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66736231/resizing-animated-gif-in-image-creates-artifacts), but the artefacts are the same. They look like this:

[image: GIF artefacts]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] then click [edit] and add your images and latest/greatest attempt at coding it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in Imagemagick as follows:

```
convert \( loren_ipsum_foreground.gif -coalesce \) -draw 'image over -20,-20 0,0 "lorem_ipsum_frame.png"' -layers optimize lorem_ipsum_animation.gif
```

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#compose_draw

Comment: This cuts off the shadow around the PNG frame, and the lower subtitle (Consectetuer sadipiscit elitr). The result should be 640x260 px, not 600x200 px.

Comment: Your answer sent me in the right direction though. I have added `-repage 640x260+20+20` to bring the GIF to the correct size first, then `-transparent white` to make the GIF's background transparent, then `-draw` without any offset. The PNG shadow isn't transparent anymore, but I guess GIF just isn't a suitable format for these kind of soft shadows, so I'll make do without them. Feel free to edit your answer a bit and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Post your corrected solution and result

Comment: Still struggling with this, as sometimes the resulting GIF shows artifacts. A possible solution is described here, but I have yet to combine it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66736231/resizing-animated-gif-in-image-creates-artifacts

Comment: Did you add -dispose XXX to your new command? Post an example input and output and your exact command

Comment: I added some details to the original question.

Comment: It is possible that artefacts will result if there are not enough colours left for encoding the animation. Careful tweaking of the palette may help to resolve that.